# AfterMapping issue on POST request - SPRING

Tags: java, spring, rest, dto, mapstruct

I have an entity named User with multiple relationships with other entities. Well, I created a DTO for this entity and a Mapper using MapStruct. 
A get request is working fine, but when trying to make a post it returns 500.

User entity:

```
@Entity(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Boolean admin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Account> accounts;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Budget budget;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
```

User DTO:

```
public class UserDto {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Boolean admin;
    private List<AccountDto> accounts;
    private BudgetDto budgetDto;
    private List<TransactionDto> transactions;

    public UserDto() {
    }

    public UserDto(String username, String password,
                   String email, Boolean admin, List<AccountDto> accounts, BudgetDto budgetDto, List<TransactionDto> transactions) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.admin = admin;
        this.accounts = accounts;
        this.budgetDto = budgetDto;
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }
```

User mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class UserMapper {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public abstract UserDto toDto(User user);

    @Mapping(target="accounts", ignore=true)
    @Mapping(target="budget", ignore=true)
    @Mapping(target="transactions", ignore=true)
    public abstract User toEntity(UserDto userDto);

    @AfterMapping
    void afterToEntity(@MappingTarget User user, UserDto userDto){
        List<AccountDto> accountDtoList = userDto.getAccounts();
        List<Long> accountIds = accountDtoList.stream().map(AccountDto::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Account> accounts = accountIds
                .stream()
                .map(id -> entityManager.find(Account.class, id))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        user.setAccounts(accounts);

        Long id = userDto.getBudgetDto().getId();
        Budget budget = entityManager.find(Budget.class, id);
        user.setBudget(budget);

        List<TransactionDto> transactionDtoList = userDto.getTransactions();
        List<Long> transactionIds = transactionDtoList.stream().map(TransactionDto::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Transaction> transactions = transactionIds
                .stream()
                .map(t_id -> entityManager.find(Transaction.class, t_id))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        user.setTransactions(transactions);
    }
}
```

User controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<UserDto> getAll() {
        List<User> categories = userService.findAll();
        return categories.stream()
                .map(userMapper::toDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public UserDto createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        User user = userMapper.toEntity(userDto);
        User userResult = userService.save(user);
        return userMapper.toDto(userResult);
    }
```

I tried to make a post request with:

{
    "admin": "true",
    "email": "x@gmail.com",
    "password": "x",
    "username": "x"
}

And it returns:

{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-02T14:15:51.825+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "trace": "java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Well, some of your codes has `NullPointerException` , check the stacktrace to identify which line of code cause this problem first.

Comment: @KenChan The UserDto I give in the body doesn't have the fields accounts, budget and transactions, so these are null. My first thought is that this is the reason why I have null pointer exception due to the fact that afterMapping is trying to assign something null.

Comment: maybe , so what does the stacktrace looks like?

Comment: If the `UserDto` doesn't have all the fields set and you try to use them as they are set then you will get a `NullPointerException`. You need to make sure in your after mapping method that you guard this.